# When I type a specifc word, it gets replaced with a random address

Tags: keyboard, hacking

I have been having a weird issue with that when I type the letters "adr", it gets auto replaced with the text 22 Avenue StreetBrisbaneQLD4000. This is beyond weird. It is annoying because I do ARM assembly programming, and have to type this frequently. My thought is that my computer has been hacked. This occurs in VS Code, in the terminal, really everywhere. What could be causing this strange issue?

Comment: It sounds like you have configured some kind of *text expander* utility, such as `autokey` or `texpander`?